# Digit Recognition: I am getting same output from canvas images

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I am creating a simple web application in Flask for hello world in ML, Digit recognition.

After training the model and testing the model with unseen images from mnist, it predicted them correctly, but while using html canvas to draw the digit, I keep getting the same output for any digit drawn.

[image]

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="280" height="280" style="border:8px solid; float: left; margin: 70px; margin-top:160px;  border-radius: 5px; cursor: crosshair;"></canvas>



<script type="text/javascript">
     var mousePressed = false;
     var lastX, lastY;
     var ctx;

     function InitThis() {
         ctx = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");

         $('#myCanvas').mousedown(function (e) {
             mousePressed = true;
             Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, false);
         });

         $('#myCanvas').mousemove(function (e) {
             if (mousePressed) {
                 Draw(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left, e.pageY - $(this).offset().top, true);
             }
         });

         $('#myCanvas').mouseup(function (e) {
             mousePressed = false;
         });

         $('#myCanvas').mouseleave(function (e) {
             mousePressed = false;
         });
     }

     function Draw(x, y, isDown) {
         if (isDown) {
             ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
             ctx.lineWidth = 5;
             ctx.lineJoin = "round";
             ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
             ctx.lineTo(x, y);
             ctx.closePath();
             ctx.stroke();
         }
         lastX = x;
         lastY = y;
     }

     function clearArea() {
         // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
         ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
     }

     </script>
```

here's the python code

```
def convertImage(imgData1):
    imgstr = re.search(b'base64,(.*)',imgData1).group(1)
    with open('output.png','wb') as output:
        output.write(base64.b64decode(imgstr))


def predict():
    imgData = request.get_data()

    convertImage(imgData)
    imgArr = cv2.imread("output.png", 0)
    imgArr = cv2.resize(imgArr, dsize=(28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    #print(imgArr)
    imgArr = np.expand_dims(imgArr, axis=0)
    new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my-model.model')
    prediction = new_model.predict(imgArr)
    return np.array_str(prediction[0])
```

Here is the output I keep getting for all the images

```
Predicted Output: [0.01503093 0.09207787 0.08750388 0.0216067  0.02371381 0.5564784 0.01984628 0.16058393 0.00308483 0.02007343]

expecting an output like [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

displaying output.png with plt.imshow(imgArr) return a blank image 
[image]

Comment: Divide the problem into two parts: (part 1) is your image transferred correctly (e.g. via plt.imshow() in python); also note that there are different conventions on how the indices of color images are ordered (28x28x3), (3x28x28), (part 2) is the neural net working. The MNIST training may be misleading because samples in the dataset are centered unlike your hand-drawn digits. Different line thickness may also have great effect.

Comment: using the plt.imshow() it returns an empty image from canvas, what can I do to correct this

Comment: Do you mean that for all images you get the same "Predicted Output", i.e. same numbers? Or that numbers are different, but you expect to have sequence of zeros and one?

Comment: Next step: divide again. If you open output.png in browser, does it look OK? Keep dividing the problem until you know exactly where to look.

Comment: Yes, all images get same output. output.png looks okay in the browser. I've added the image output above.

Comment: Can you please add all the code of your html and js, like how are you getting the image of the canvas and sending it to the server ?